# Excel: why is the average of divisions different from division of sums?

Tags: excel, sum, average

So lets say I have two variables `x` and `y`. I calculate the total sum of each variable.

I calculate `y/x` for each row and also calculate `y/x` for the sum of both `x` and `y` columns (280/10=28).

I would expect this value (28) to be equal to the average of `y/x` (230/4=32.5), but it is different.

This might have a simple explanation, but I can't seem to find it.

[image: An example here]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its simply math:
`(y1+y2+y3+y4)/(x1+x2+x3+x4) != (y1/x1+y2/x2+y3/x3+y4/x4)/4`

Answer (score 4):

This is really a mathematics question. The two are not equal:

```
                        10    200    30    40
                        ─── + ──── + ─── + ─── 
10 + 200 + 30 + 40       1      2     3     4  
──────────────────  ≠  ────────────────────────
   1 + 2 + 3 + 4                   4
```

There really is no reason why they could be expected to be the same: when the second expression is rewritten with one common denominator, it becomes even more evident there is little it has in common with the first expression.

To get a common denominator, one finds the [least common denominator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator), which in this case is 12, and so the second expression could be written as follows:

```
 120   1200    120    120  
──── + ──── + ──── + ──── 
 12     12     12     12 
──────────────────────────
            4
```

Which is simplified to:

```
120 + 1200 + 120 + 120   5 + 50 + 5 + 5   65
────────────────────── = ────────────── = ── = 32.5
          48                    2          2
```

There clearly is no relation with the first expression.

#### What *is* equal?

```
10 + 200 + 30 + 40   AVG(10, 200, 30, 40)
────────────────── = ────────────────────
   1 + 2 + 3 + 4       AVG(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This works because you really divide both numerator and denominator with the same factor (4), which is a null-operation.